# How to clean liquid cooler radiator?

Tags: cpu-cooler

Is there a way to clean a pc liquid cooler radiator in order to remove the dust?
I bought a second hand one from Ebay and it's full of dust. I believe it should be clean before putting it into my case, right?

Comment: Compressed air in a can, always a winner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An airoduster or similar compressed air can clears all dust, but you want to then use a cloth duster or vacuum to remove it somewhere.

If you can't get compressed air you can try just blowing through - not as effective.

It's pretty easy, really. Take you 5 minutes.